# Как назначить метод showInfoWindow() Маркерам без события нажатия?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Здравствуйте, дописываю приложение на андройд где активно используется GoogleMap api v2 карта. Имеется массив объектов(в будущем маркеров) которые отображаются на карте. Предыдущий разработчик реализовал добавление маркеров на карту программно 
через for each таким образом:

```
for (MarkerOptions marker : markers) ///markers-это ArrayList markers options
    {


        googleMap.addMarker(marker);

    //googleMap.addMarker(marker).showInfoWindow();////////////////////////////////raffa mod
    //googleMap.get

        builder.include(marker.getPosition());


    }
```

Как мне реализовать метод showInfoWindow()  всем маркерам на карте без нажатия на маркеры?

Comment: Немного не понял, чего вы хотите. Чтобы все маркеры разом, автоматически попапы показали? Или что?

Comment: да, чтобы не при нажатии на маркеры -окошки над ними вылазили, а автоматом при инициализации карты

Comment: marker.performClick() подходит?

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что к marker так не доберешься, объект создается не явно Marker marker равно и т.д., маркеры в моем случае добавляются по типу map.addmarker(markerOptions) через цикл for each, в том то и проблема

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, подойдет ли вам такой вариант, но всё же. 
В вашем цикле for each, после добавления маркера, можете сразу же вызывать showInfoWindow(). Таким образом, для всех маркеров, которые вы ставите, будут включены информационные окна.

```
for (MarkerOptions marker : markers) ///markers-это ArrayList markers options
{

    googleMap.addMarker(marker).showInfoWindow();

}
```

Сейчас пытаюсь разобраться с гугл картами, есть похожий код, я попробовал сделать так - всё работает.

Comment: Спасибо,Пробовал такой вариант,выпадает в exception

Comment: @GoodRA а что за exception? можно подробнее?

Comment: В ошибку,unfornatelly,н е дебажил и по логам не смотрел  просто